# My own implementation of MPI_Gather

Tags: c++, concurrency, mpi

I am trying to write my own implementation of MPI_Gather, but the array at the input is not changing with the out. The normal MPI_gather works properly.

The code:

```
void My_MPI_Gather(int* sendbuf, int sendcount, MPI_Datatype d1, int* recvbuf, int recvcount, MPI_Datatype d2, int root, MPI_Comm comm)
{
    int numprocs, myid;
    int *temp = new int[sendcount];
    int temp2;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &myid);

    if (myid == root)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numprocs; i++)
        {
            if (i != root)
            {
                MPI_Recv(sendbuf, recvcount, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, *sendbuf, &status);
                for (int j = 0; j < recvcount; j++)
                {
                    recvbuf[recvcount*i + j] = *temp;
                }
            }
            recvbuf[root*recvcount] = *sendbuf;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Send(temp, sendcount, d1, root, 99, *recvbuf);
    }
}
```

The worst thing in MPI is that I cant debug this function, so I would be greatful for any advice :)

Comment: If this is not an exercise, better use the gather function from the mpi library. The hardware/library can do better than this. For example, root node gather data from nodes 1, 2. Node 1 gather data from nodes 3, 4, 5, 6. And Node 2 gather data from nodes 7, 8, 9, 10. The communication burden on the root node is less this way. The communication pattern should match the physical communication paths (the ethernet cable/infiniband connection etc). Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum

Comment: This is exercise, but thank you :(

Comment: That code makes no sense on many levels, and your compiler should be able to tell you the worst issues. Further in: declare variables as locally as possible and try to compile again. When in doubt - track the value of variables across specific code paths.

Comment: Note your function will only work if used with `MPI_INT`. At first glance, I was able to spot 3 distinct issues, so I recommend you take a step back and give it some more thoughts. You can take this opportunity to learn how to debug a MPI app, and write a [MCVE]